# Visual Studio 2010: Visual Debugger Drill down into collection pain

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, collections, drilldown

When I am debugging a collection visually in Visual Studio 2010 I have to drill down quite a few levels before I get to the actual items in the collection. The image attached below is of an `ObservableCollection<Fundsource>` and you can see the hoops I need to go through to look at the items. It didn't used to be like this and I'm wondering if I have changed some setting to see all the intermediates. (Or maybe the implementation has changed between VS2005 and now and I'm just remembering the good ol' days).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to uncheck this option:  Tools | Options | Debugging | General | Show raw structure of objects in variables window.